# Changing IP address from dhcp to static

Tags: powershell, dhcp, static-ip-address

I've written a powershell script that works for windows 10 but not older versions of powershell.  It also throws an CIMs error on some PCs.  The real trouble it that it doesn't work on the 200ish PCs I need to change; Windows 7 PCs, each in a different network.

I need this to get an IP, change the last octet, and then set the IP; I can run it from LANDesk but it needs to work across any version of Windows, so I think powershell is out?

I'm not well versed at scripting in general, and I've only worked in Powershell, however, this doesn't need to be powershell.

My somewhat working, somewhat broken script:

```
$computername = HOSTNAME.EXE
$info = Get-NetIPAddress -CimSession $computername -AddressFamily IPv4 | where { $_.InterfaceAlias -notmatch 'Loopback'} | Select PSComputername,IPAddress,InterfaceIndex
$ip = $info.IPAddress
$intindex = $info.InterfaceIndex

write "IP: "$ip
write "InterfaceIndex: "$intindex

$ip2 = $ip.split('.')
$ip2[-1] = 80
$newip = $ip2 -join "." 

Write "New IP: "$newip

Set-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $intindex -IPAddress $newip -PrefixLength 24 -WhatIf
```

Comment: Just for reference: `Get-NetIPAddress` and `Set-NetIPAddress` only work on Windows 8+ / Windows Server 2012+. - https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh826151.aspx

Comment: Take a look at (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/02/28/use-powershell-to-configure-static-ip-and-dns-settings/). This should help you out.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the IP for the scriptingguy link you gave me.  Each computer will be in a different network and I'll need to pull the network octets and add the PCs host octet.

Comment: The relevant part from the post was a Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WMI object holds the info that you need. e.g. `(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled = 'True'").IPAddress` and the methods to set the IP address to the updated value.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [BenH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6788803/benh) and [Paxz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6404133/paxz)!

I have a solution to this using wmi:

```
$ip = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object { $_.IPAddress } | Select-Object -Expand IPAddress | Where-Object { $_ -like '10.*' }
$ip2 = $ip.split('.')
$ip2[-1] = 80
$newip = $ip2 -join "."
$gateway = (Get-wmiObject Win32_networkAdapterConfiguration | ?{$_.IPEnabled}).DefaultIPGateway
$wmi = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "ipenabled = 'true'"
$wmi.EnableStatic($newip ,"255.255.255.0")
$wmi.SetGateways($gateway,1)
$wmi.SetDNSServerSearchOrder("10.x.x.x")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change IP address from dhcp to static using PowerShell:

```
   $interface.EnableStatic("192.168.1.25","255.255.255.0") | out-null
   $interface.SetGateways("192.168.2.15") 
   $interface.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($dnsRecords) 
   $interface.SetDynamicDNSRegistration($false)
```